# Can a jqGrid group summary be refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, grouping, summary

I am using two jqGrids (in javascript) to achieve master-detail information.  The master table uses grouping and group summaries rows as well as a total footer summary.  A single column of the details table is editable.

When a user updates the details row, I am able to update the master row and the master table's footer using the following code.  However, since the group summaries have no rowid, I can't find any hooks to get the group summary row to update.  (It is not automatically recalculated when a row in the group is set.)

```
    jQuery(this).footerData('set',{ae:aeTotal});     //details footer
    jQuery('#grid').footerData('set',{ae:newEpaAe}); //master footer
    jQuery('#grid').setCell(rowId, 'ae', aeTotal);   //master row
    //master group summary??
```

[image: Values circled in green update. Interested in handle to value circled in red.]

Is there a way to refresh a group's summary row (value circled in red) without reloading the entire grid?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I have still not had any luck gaining hooks into the roll-up summary footer.  Is it possible to use the header's row id (i.e. listghead_0_0) to gain access to this data?

My main objective in updating the tables this way is to avoid reloading the entire master grid.  If there is a way to reload a single row, that would also work in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandeep, your response got me on the right track.  See the correct re-group code below.

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('groupingRemove');
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', 'data');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to destroy headers and regrouping with setGroupHeaders

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('destroyGroupHeader');
```

and to regroup

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: true, 
  groupHeaders:[
    {startColumnName: 'amount', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: '<em>Price</em>'},
    {startColumnName: 'closed', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Shiping'}
  ]
});
...
```

(From wiki)

Refreshing group headers doesnt seem to be possible.